# Malfacilo? Malfacileco? Malfacilaĵo?

Tags: word-difference

Pardonu min por krokodili. I'm having a hard time understanding the difference among these three words: malfacilo, malfacileco, malfacilaĵo. I suppose they all mean "difficulty" but what's the difference? For example,

> This project is doable but there will be many difficulties.

Should it be translated as *Ĉi tiu projekto estas farebla, sed estos multe da malfacilaĵoj.*, since we are talking about specific obstacles (that we may overcome) here?

Comment: La tipo de radiko havas gravan rolon en kunmetaĵoj. Kelkaj radikoj jam estas iel ecaj, kiel `facil`, aŭ `bon`.kaj en tiuj okazoj la signifo de kunmetaĵo kun `ec` estas malsama. Nepra lego: [sufikso ec en PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/ec.html).

Answer (score 1):

Any word with the "-eco" suffix includes the idea of "essence" in its meaning. So "malfacileco", although it doesn't have a direct English translation, might be translated as something like the "essence of difficulty", or "difficultness". Generally then, you wouldn't use this in your example sentence. That said, there are three examples of "malfacilecoj" (as a plural) in tekstaro.com, used in similar contexts.

"Malfacilaĵo" = "io malfacila". As you say, that means a specific, often a concrete thing.

PIV (vortaro.net) defines "malfacilo" as equivalent to both "malfacilaĵo" and "malfacileco", so it's rather ambiguous.

> Should it be translated as Ĉi tiu projekto estas farebla, sed estos multe da malfacilaĵoj.

Yes, based on the above, I agree.